# Samsung S3 wont sync

Tags: sync, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy S3 but it takes forever to connect with my laptop and i am unsure why this is.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It takes forever to sync with Kies you mean?

Comment: as in the connect symbol just cycles for ages sometimes an hour before it works sometimes not even.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems like yours with Kies, and I really hate it, but it's an necessary evil for some tasks. Here some things I did, try them:

- Make sure you are running the lastest version of Kies
- Change the USB port you are trying to connect
- If you have another computer to test, try it
- [KiesAir](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.swift.app.kiesair&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zYW1zdW5nLnN3aWZ0LmFwcC5raWVzYWlyIl0.) or [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zYW5kLmFpcmRyb2lkIl0.) maybe fit your needs
- There's a [Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
- Try reinstalling Kies
- Make sure the storage mode is **on**

If none of this works, try contacting Samsung