# Connecting Sony Xperia U with my Windows XP laptop

Tags: usb-connection-mode

I am unable to link my phone with my laptop. When I connect the USB it says st25i camera connected. I use a Sony Xperia U model and my laptop has Windows XP OS. What can be the issue?

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. See if you can find the correct drivers for you phone on the Sony website.

Comment: maybe this help: [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33118/samsung-s3-wont-sync/33123#33123)

Comment: When connected via USB, pull down your notification bar and check whether it has an "USB" entry. You might be able here to select the connection mode from e.g. "charge only", "MTP", "USB mass storage". If it's not there, check in the common *Settings* menu (usually *Settings->Connections->USB connection*) what is available.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably driver issue, following resources may help you

- http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/42763?start=0&tstart=0
- http://www.priceandspecification.in/sony-xperia-u-pc-suite-pc-companion-software-download.html
- http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to install a Sony Pc Companions in your pc and then connect the device through it. after this u can share, transfer the pic and docs. you can download it from sony xperia site which is easily available.

Rao Saahil Umar

Comment: Why would you need a companion suite to connect a device and share its storage? How would users on Linux/MacOS and other systems do that then (as most of those "suites" are Windows-only)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on My Computer icon (on desktop) then Click "Manage"
2. Click on Device Manager, and select "Portable Devices" from the list. Double click on Device Manager and select ST25i (Your phone Device) from the list.
3. Right click on ST25i (Your phone Device) and click "Update Driver..." from the list (which will open a Hardware Update Wizard)
4. Click "Install the software automatically (Recommended)", then Next and 
   the wizard will search for correct Update automatically.
5. Click on Finish.